# Question about Squaring a Function

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, square-numbers

I am trying to write the Kinetic energy Lagrangian for a certain situation. This is a portion of the work leading to the correct answer given by my professor.

$$\text {Kinetic Energy}=T=\frac {1}{2}mv^2$$ 
$$v (\text{in cylindrical coordinates})= \dot{\rho}+\rho \dot{\phi}+\dot{z} $$

$$v^2 = \dot {\rho ^2}+\rho ^2 \dot{\phi ^2}+\dot{z^2}$$

So, this seems like a dumb question, but why is $v^2$ just the components of v, just squared, instead of.

$$(\dot{\rho}+\rho \dot{\phi}+\dot{z})(\dot{\rho}+\rho \dot{\phi}+\dot{z})$$

$$\dot{\rho^2}+\dot{\rho}\rho \dot{\phi}+\dot{\rho}\dot{z}+\dot{\rho}\rho \dot{\phi}+\rho ^2 \dot{\phi ^2}+\rho \dot{\phi}\dot{z}+\dot{\rho}\dot{z}+\rho \dot{\phi}\dot{z}+\dot{z^2}$$
Which does not equal $\dot {\rho ^2}+\rho ^2 \dot{\phi ^2}+\dot{z^2}$ at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, velocity $\vec v$ is a vector and hence it is only correct to write $\vec v = \dot{\rho} \hat \rho+\rho \dot{\phi}\hat \phi +\dot{z} \hat z $

And it is from here that we get,
$$v^2=\vec v\cdot \vec v=(\dot{\rho} \hat \rho+\rho \dot{\phi}\hat \phi +\dot{z} \hat z )\cdot (\dot{\rho} \hat \rho+\rho \dot{\phi}\hat \phi +\dot{z} \hat z )=\dot {\rho ^2}+\rho ^2 \dot{\phi ^2}+\dot{z^2}$$

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Do you mean that you never use the binomial expansion rule for any vectors?

Comment: @JLui What do you mean by the binomial expansion rule of vectors? Even if there is something like that, I have never used it.

Comment: Well I mean binomial expansion for scalar quantities $(a+b)^2$ can't be used if it were, for example vectors $(\vec{a}+\vec{b})^2$?

Comment: Oh! you edited your answer. is the dot in $\vec {v} * \vec{v}$ the dot product?

Comment: @JLui Well I have used it earlier obviously.. However that is not relevant here ... I had posted my answer a little bit early by mistake.. perhaps that is what is creating confusion... Anyway, please check if my answersolves your problem..

Comment: @JLui Yes it is the vector dot product.

Comment: Ok! makes sense now! Thank you!

Comment: @JLui You're welcome.